# First time android programmer can't move between activities

Tags: java, android, mobile

This is my first time programming for android and in java.
I am using the latest Android Studio.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
    nametxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Txtname);
    final Button nextbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextButton);
    nametxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            nextbutton.setEnabled(!(nametxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
nextbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    editor.putString("Name",nametxt.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
    Intent nextScreen = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(nextScreen);
}
});

}
```

In this code I am trying to get the user's name, save it in the android preferences file, and then move to the next screen.
Well haha it doesn't work.
Any idea why?
Thank Alot

Comment: correct method is -->  editor.commit()

Comment: what does "doesnt work" mean..Please tell your exact problem..

Comment: When I click on the next button, nothing happends

Comment: Try: Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainMenu.class);

Comment: Try `Intent nextScreen = new Intent(youractivityname.this, MainMenu.class);` instead of `Intent nextScreen = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);`

Comment: tried `Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainMenu.class);` Still doesn't work
Also the app crashed right away with the code for saving the prefrences give me 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: did you try what i said??? @Dani G

Comment: Yes I did It Works!!
Is there a way to make an invisible button that will still work when clicked on?

Comment: Any idea why it crashes when I add the lines to save the preferences? @Lal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my comment to the question...

I've specified in the comment to

Try

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(youractivityname.this, MainMenu.class);
```

instead of

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainMenu.class);
```

Because you will have to pass the current `Context` as the argument.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any idea why it crashes when I add the lines for saving the prefrences?

Comment: An invisible button doesnt work when clicked..What actually do you need???Can you please specify it clearly..

Comment: Try after Replacing `editor.apply();` with `editor.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

try to change last 2 lines into this:

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(this_activity_name.this, MainMenu.class);
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

where this_activity_name have to be the name of your current activity.